# Laravel: company validation using regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I don't have any idea about how to use regex. I want to validate my company field.

For example:

1. url.co
2. url.com
3. url.in

Right now my PHP script takes any string but I want to validate it according to the website URL which contains

> string + . + any domain

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{    
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mobile_no' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10'],
        'company' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],

    ]);
}
```

Comment: If you want to validate url, Laravel provides it out of the box. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-url Your validation would go: `'company' => ['required', 'url', 'max:255']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $messages = [
        'company.regex' => 'Invalid format.'
    ];

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mobile_no' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10'],
        'company' => ['required', 'max:255', "regex:/\b((http|https):\/\/?)[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|\/?))/"],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],

    ],$messages);
}
```